# In need of a code that will enable text boxes on hover?

Tags: html, css, hover, mousehover

Key word of my post is boxe***s***, emphasis on the plural. The code I am using will not allow me to reuse the hover on multiple pieces of text. Only one of the hovers will work at a time and the rest are frozen in place, as if they were text boxes with no hover (no hide and then reveal).

Please help me! I appreciate any input.

Here is the link to the code:
http://pastebin.com/dRgj8e1D

Comment: Can we get a little code to help understand what it is your trying to do?

Comment: http://testpage4321.tumblr.com/

Comment: There's an awful lot of Tumblr code in there making it hard to find what you're talking about. Is your implementation in JavaScript or CSS?

Comment: I am sorry about that here is the blank code: http://pastebin.com/dRgj8e1D

Comment: In future, please include relevant code in the question itself. Better still use StackOVerflow's code snippet feature, it is the **<>** button in the question editor.

Answer (score 0):

Basically your code is only setting up toggling for the very first toggle, as shown in the `window.onload` section. To make multiple instances work, you would need to get the ID of each toggle button and call the toggle setup function for each one.

An easier way to accomplish this would be to change the ID on the button to a class and use hover styles in the CSS:

```
.togContent   {
    display: none;
}
.togTrigger:hover + .togContent {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help with this, David. I'm new to this coding business, so thank you for bearing with me. In order to implement the changes you noted, should I just copy and replace these CSS styles for what is already in the code? And should this satisfy the class changes without any further steps? I am unsure how to change the ID to a class..

Comment: You can just copy and paste this into your style tags and then change `id="togTrigger"` to `class="togTrigger"`.